# I’m looking for a book about a boy with super powers who is in a club of such people

Tags: story-identification

About a year or two ago, I read this book about a boy with super power. I'll explain the bits and pieces I remember from the book but I don’t know the authors  name or the title of the book.

It was about this boy: I think his name either started with an I or a C. Not 100 percent certain, but I believe he went to this college study club for kids with a bunch of other students. Only a select few are in this club and they basically have super powers.

One day they're doing the regular at the club, training and stuff, when a group of people break in and kidnap their teacher. The group of kids end up in the hospital, and while they're there this man comes up to some of them and tries to recruit them for this “secret organization” of people like them and they’ll apparently help them find their teacher. So obviously the main character accepts.

I don’t really remember anything in the middle of that but I do remember that at the end of the book the main character get betrayed by someone and his emotions are all over the place and he loses control. As far as I can remember, the cover of the book was blue with a couple of characters on the front using their powers, It was not a hard cover book, so it was paperback.

If anyone is able to identify the book it would be a great help.

Comment: Do you happen to remember what any of the "super powers" are? Can they levitate, read minds, start fires, walk on water? Do they all have the same super powers or are they all different?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.